# Regular expression in Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

how can I use regex in Smartface for editboxes' text area?

Can someone give an example?

Should I write the expression to the text area directly or it must be done another way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of regular expression you need.

A simple usage will be as below :

```
var price = '$55.99';
var priceRegex = /[(0-9)+.?(0-9)*]+/igm;
var price2 = parseFloat(priceRegex.exec(price));
var myEditbox1 = new SMF.UI.EditBox({
    text : price,
    top : "20%"
});
var myEditbox2 = new SMF.UI.EditBox({
    text : price2,
    top : "50%"
});
```

I used a priceRegex as a regular expression in script file. 
You can add these two editbox objects to your page in order to see the result.